# number of graphs satisfying specific degrees and number of vertices.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Is there a way to determine the number of graphs (up to isomorphism) for a given $n$ and multi set $\{ d_1,d_2...d_n \}$ ?

such that the graphs have $n$ vertices and $\{ d_1,d_2...d_n \}$ is the multiset of the degrees of the vertices.

Comment: You have several sequences that compute that in some specific cases : http://oeis.org/wiki/User:Jason_Kimberley/C_k-reg_girth_ge_g_index

Comment: nice, what about the general case?